# Openvpn exclude ip in pool

Tags: ubuntu, ip, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server running on a Linux Ubuntu box. Multiple clients connect to this server (500+) and that is why I set the server-bridge option like this:

```
server-bridge 10.0.100.1 255.255.0.0 10.0.200.1 10.0.210.254
```

This works perfectly. The clients get a dynamic IP address, and it goes from the 200 block to the 201 block when the number of client exceed 255.

I have an internal application that connects to these clients, but this application crashes on IP addresses 10.0.200.255 and 10.0.201.0.

These IP addresses are in the range I supplied, but I can't use them.

Is there a way to exclude them from my pool?

Or do I need change my setup?

Comment: The internal application should be fixed.  .0 and .255 are valid addresses as long as they do not start or end the network range (i.e. in your case 10.0.210.255 is not valid, but you have correctly excluded it, likewise 10.0.200.0).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know they are valid addresses. That was not the question though. I would like to change the config of the OpenVPN server to fix this. for example in PPTP we could set remoteip like this: 10.0.200.1-254,10.0.201.1-254,10.0.202.1-254,etc

Answer (score 2):

Using multiple IP ranges or excluding certain IPs is not directly possible with OpenVPN's built-in DHCP server using a single configuration file.

I propose 3 possible solutions:

- **Workaround**, but not guaranteed to work
- **DHCP-proxy mode**, simple, clean and lots of other options
- **Multiple instances**, more complex, could have performance benefits

However, I recommend to fix the root cause of the problem, the internal application that is flawed.

### Workaround

In the server configuration file add:

```
server-bridge 10.0.100.1 255.255.0.0 10.0.200.1 10.0.210.254
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt 0
```

The `0` at the end of the directive `ifconfig-pool-persist` treats `ipp.txt` as a read-only configuration file.

Create a file `/etc/openvpn/ipp.txt`:

```
reserved-not-used-cn-1,10.0.200.255
reserved-not-used-cn-2,10.0.201.0
reserved-not-used-cn-3,10.0.201.255
...
```

Add all the reserved IP-addresses to this file, formatted as `<Common-Name>,<IP-address>`. For the value in field `<Common-Name>` choose something that will never by used in any client certificate.

**This is not guaranteed to work always, as stated in the OpenVPN manpage:**

> Note  that the entries in this file are treated by OpenVPN as suggestions only, based on past associations between a common name and IP address.  They do not guarantee that the given common name will always receive the given IP address.  If you want guaranteed assignment, use `--ifconfig-push`

### DHCP-proxy mode

Since you are using a **TAP** setup, this might be the best solution. It allows to use a fully featured **DHCP server** on the server side subnet or on the server itself, depending on the configuration. To configure ethernet bridging, you must first use your OS's bridging capability to bridge the TAP interface with another interface.

**OpenVPN** server config:

```
server-bridge
```

This directive expands as follows:

```
mode server
tls-server
push "route-gateway dhcp"
```

**DHCPD** server config:

```
subnet 10.0.100.1 netmask 255.255.0.0 {
  range 10.0.200.1 10.0.200.254;
  range 10.0.201.1 10.0.201.254;
  range 10.0.202.1 10.0.202.254;
  range 10.0.203.1 10.0.203.254;
  ...
}
```

### Multiple instances

An alternative would be to create a separate openvpn instance for each `/24` subnet, using multiple configuration files. But this requires using a different port for each instance.

Instance 1 config file:

```
port 11941
server-bridge 10.0.100.1 255.255.0.0 10.0.200.1 10.0.200.254
```

Instance 2 config file:

```
port 11942
server-bridge 10.0.100.1 255.255.0.0 10.0.201.1 10.0.201.254
```

...

This would require:

- either IP-range specific client configurations with the respective port numbers,
- or e.g. to use `iptables` load balancing on incoming connections on port `1194` and distribute them evenly across the instances

This solution could have performance benefits, as explained [here](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?p=7923#p7923).

Comment: I tried the first option, as it is the least drastic. I got this warning at start [ WARNING: --ifconfig-pool-persist will not work with --duplicate-cn]. Although it did loop through the file and gave me lines like these: [ifconfig_pool_read(), in='never-use-this-address-1,10.0.200.255'], it neglected to do anything with it.

Comment: Then I guess this method does not work when you are using `--duplicate-cn`.

Comment: @spambas, I have just been thinking about another solution if you just want to make a workaround. You could write a script which handles the IP assignments and is invoked with `client-connect` and `client-disconnect`. The command is also passed the pathname of a freshly created temporary file as the last argument, to be used by the script to pass dynamically generated config file directives back to OpenVPN. Then you write the `ifconfig-push` directive in this temporary file for custom client configuration. In the script you would need to manage the IP pool manually. But you are in full control